# sql query - how to find the engineers that work in all projects

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 tables, engineer(id,name), project(id,name,description),works(engineer_id,project_id) and i want to find the engineers that work in all projects

thank.

Comment: You need to provide sample input and and sample output.

Comment: Have a look at `JOIN`, that will work. If it does not, post what you tried and we will have a look at possible bugs

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name
FROM engineer as e 
INNER JOIN works as w ON e.id = w.engineer_id
GROUP BY e.id, e.name
HAVING COUNT(w.project_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project);
```

[**Sample demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02e8a0/3)

This works as following:

- Join the three tables.
- Group by engineer id and name.
- Having clause to select only those with project id equal to the total count of the projects from the projects table.

Comment: @HananAvraham The query have three tables as well. And If you check the demo, it gives the correct results. Please show some sample data from your tables. Did you tried the demo??

Comment: Think using HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.project_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project); is even better

Answer (score 0):

No need to do INNER JOIN PROJECT as we are already doing
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project

find below sql with data

```
WITH engineer AS (
SELECT 1::int AS id, 'a'::VARCHAR AS name
UNION
SELECT 2::int AS id, 'b'::VARCHAR AS name
UNION
SELECT 3::int AS id, 'c'::VARCHAR AS name
),
project AS (
SELECT 1::int AS id, 'p1'::VARCHAR AS name
UNION
SELECT 2::int AS id, 'p2'::VARCHAR AS name
UNION
SELECT 3::int AS id, 'p3'::VARCHAR AS name
UNION
SELECT 4::int AS id, 'p4'::VARCHAR AS name
),
works AS (
SELECT 1::int AS eng_id, 1::int project_id
UNION
SELECT 1::int AS eng_id, 2::int project_id
UNION
SELECT 2::int AS eng_id, 1::int project_id
UNION
SELECT 2::int AS eng_id, 3::int project_id
UNION
SELECT 2::int AS eng_id, 2::int project_id
UNION
SELECT 3::int AS eng_id, 2::int project_id
)
SELECT 
     e.id, 
     e.name
FROM 
    engineer AS e 
    INNER JOIN works AS w ON (e.id = w.eng_id)
GROUP BY 
    e.id, 
    e.name
HAVING COUNT(w.project_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project)
```

Comment: 1::int is PostgreSQL syntax and WiTH .. AS () wont be supported as off MySQL's version 8

Comment: @RaymondNijland WITH clauses are given for example data only, actual query will be the last one. OP doesn't need to run full query in mysql, only last part is enough for him.